How can I fix custom Auth macros not working in Laravel 11?
I am try above code but getting below error in laravel 11
But same code i am try in laravel 10 then its working fine.
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::member does not exist.

app/Providers/MacroServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Auth::macro('member', function () {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if ($user) {
                return $user->member;
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}

bootstrap/providers.php
<?php

return [
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\MacroServiceProvider::class,
];

PostController.php
public function create(CreateRequest $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    try {
        $working_member = $user->member; // working code
        $member = Auth::member(); // error code
        return $member;
    }catch (\Exception $exception){
        return $exception->getMessage();
    }
}

I am try above code but getting below error in laravel 11
But same code i am try in laravel 10 then its working fine.
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::member does not exist.


Were you able to find a solution?
